# PagerAdapter getCount() is called many times

Tags: android, android-pageradapter, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. for some reason the getCount() method is beeing called a lot of times before any fragment is even visible... Is it a normal behavior?

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: My question is in generral: is it normal for a FragmentStatePagerAdapter.getCount() to be called alot of times or is it not?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? It's being called about 100 times.

Answer (score 1):

yes.  Don't worry about it.  It seems to be called 10 times more often than getItem()